# How do I import other python code from a directory?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I have a directory structure like this:

```
root
--child
-----config.py
example.py
```

In `example.py` I just tried:

```
import child
```

but that doesn't seems to be working.

Where I'm making the mistake!

Comment: Did you try `import child.config`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `__init__.py` file in `root/child/` directory? After creating this file you should be able to do this:

```
import child.config
```

or

```
from child import config
```

You can also import multiple modules from child directory like this:

```
from child import first, second, third
```

Read about modules and packages [here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import `config.py` with importing `child` you need to define `child` as a package.

To do so you need to create an `__init__.py` file in your `child` directory.

Check this about [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 1):

Your directory should have **init**.py so that python will understand it is a package. So the directory structure would be like

```
root
     __init__.py
     child
         __init__.py
         config.py

example.py
import root.child
```

note, you should import `root.child` not `child`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `__init__.py` file in same directory with `config.py`. This is required for importing files like a package.

Then you can import it.